# Convert to Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to covert the following to Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) and cannot get the answer.

(¬A ∨ C) → B

Can anybody explain how to get the correct answer?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Don't just assert that you can't get the answer: show what you've done.

Comment: Hint: $p \rightarrow q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$.